# How to create a content type with associated products and customized attributes?

Tags: views, nodes

I am creating a little CRM at work and I have two content types:

1. Offers - with some text fields and references to users and companies.
2. Products - very simple with SKU, Title, Price

Now I want to attached some products to Offers and then alter their attributes like price, add quantity and then display all this as a view with the total amount of all prices sum together.

The final goal is to have multiple offers referencing products but with own price and quantity.

I hope this is not to confusing? I tried already entity reference but then I cannot at a custom price or quantity to those products.

Comment: do you have any advance?

Comment: Yes, but now I am figuring out how to create a proper view with all the information :)

Comment: I think that you must to close (accept one answer here) this question, and open (create) a new question because if you modify this question to put your new requirement this question will be closed as too broad. So create a new question with the new scenario an let me know here to see if I can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, I am new to this board :) I selected your response.

Comment: If you want to know how this site works, take the tour  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I will do! Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.

And create a Field collection field (in your Offer Content Type) with a [reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to Product and a field named quantity and other named custom price.

So in your Offer you can have many Products with theirs quantities and custom prices.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up, using Businesses and Events. 
Events have a Entity Reference Field which links it to whichever business is selected. On the View for this display, I added a Relationship using the Entity Reference field:Content and the Contextual Filter:Content ID this will get any "items" directly related to the Business associated with it.

Not sure this answers what you're looking for. But hope it helps a little bit.